# Scope for private posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

So I got a simple scope:

```
scope :visible_to, -> (user) {user && (user.premium? || user.admin?) ? all : where(:private => false || nil) }
```

The idea is that it shows (on index) a list of private and public post if the users role equals to `Premium` or `Admin`. Seems to work correctly when I am logged in as Admin or Premium. But if I'm not logged in or logged in as a `Standard` user ( default role) only nil post are displayed. How can I make it work for both standard and guest users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you want to show posts that

- have `private` set to `false` or `nil` when there is no user or user is neither admin nor not premium
- if user is admin or premium then show all posts

So you can try this:

```
class Post
  scope :visible_to, -> (user) do
    return all if user && (user.premium? || user.admin?)
    where(private: [false, nil])
   end
end
```

Some recommendations/ideas:

- make sure that `private` is either true or false, do not allow nil. Will simplify all the queries
- rename the `private` attribute. It might get confused with the `private` key word of ruby itself

Another way to check for it goes a bit another way. Always show `false` and `nil` and include `true` when admin/premium:

```
class Post 
  scope :visible_to, ->(user) do
    values = [false, nil]
    values << true if (user.try!(:premium?) user.try!(:admin?))
    where(private: values)
  end
end
```

Comment: You are correct and it worked thank you very much. And the reason a few posts are nil for private is because they come from seeded data that i didnt specify true or false. sorry :(

Comment: You can specify a default value in the DB or convert nil to false when seeding. This will simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
scope :visible_to, -> (user) {(user && (user.premium? || user.admin?)) ? all : where(:private => [false,nil]) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This way `Users.visible_to` will return premium and admin users.

```
scope :visible_to, -> (user) do
  where(users.premium? = ? OR users.admin? = ?, true, true)
end
```